# Failure to update Maven in Eclipse oxygen version

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse oxygen which I updated from neon by the help - 'check for updates' tab. I like to keep Eclipse up to date and today's check for updates contacted the sites, then produced the following errors when I selected the two maven items:

*An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=_home_nick_eclipse_jee-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.importer,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.8.1.20170728-1531 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.8.1.20170728-1531*

Any suggestions for a solution would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE 2nd AUGUST  - SOLVED BY A FLUKE**

Firstly, I should add that I have a fast and reliable internet connection and that recently the 'check for updates' function has been taking longer and longer, with the percentage complete figure at the bottom right of eclipse slowly creeping up.

After that finished, it noted that two m2e components were available and whilst the 'accept licence' radio button selection was dislayed, Eclipse was downloading items, as displayed bottom right. These were largely hidden by a shortening to a URL with an ellipsis but did contain an 'artifacts.jar. and some xml files.

I waited for the bottom right display to become clear (presuming the downloading had finished- as it took a while) and then clicked 'accept' button for the licence agreement. After that, Eclipse needed restarting and then it was up to date.

For anyone else having similar problems, I thought this update may be useful. As a note to Eclipse, I would suggest that a 'please wait' popup might be a good thing to have, whilst all the mysterious stuff is downloading

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by installing new software rather than updating existing software. I used the update link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases and it is possible that eclipse was looking for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e which was never going to work.

After selecting that I wanted to install the software, eclipse changed my request from an install to an update, detecting that I already had the previous version installed.

I then followed the suggestion above which was to wait for all network activity to finish before continuing the update process. This took about a minute. Then when I continued it was able to update to the new version successfully.